# ASP.Net MVC validation not working with Bootstrap Select Picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've issue with ASP.NET MVC validation not working with Bootstrap Select Picker, If I remove the selectpicker class from dropdown list the validation working fine and if I added it the validation not working , Any help please

The MVC Code :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocationID, Model.lstOfLocations, "Select Delivery Location", new { @class = " selectpicker", @placeholder = "" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLocationID)
```

The Jquery Code With Valida-min.js

```
 $(".SearchForm").validate({
        ignore: ':not(select:hidden, input:visible, textarea:visible)',
        rules: {
            SelectedLocationID: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if ($(element).is('Select Delivery Location')) {
                element.next().after(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: please show us your code, otherwise I don't now how we're going to be able to help you!

Comment: Could you also post your viewmodel?

Comment: you shouldn't need to use Jquery for this in mvc. Have a look in your Controller and Model! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question while searching for fix for same issue.

The problem arises from fact, that Bootstrap hides original select element and creates it's own elements to handle UI for dropdown list. In the meantime, jQuery validation by default ignores invisible fields.

I fixed this with workaround which combines [changing validation ignore list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315242/validation-of-bootstrap-select-using-jquery-validate-plugin) and [finding parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311579/jquery-js-how-do-i-select-the-parent-form-based-on-which-submit-button-is-cli). Final code snippet in my case looks like this

```js
        if ($(".selectpicker")[0]) {
            $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
            $('.selectpicker').parents('form:first').validate().settings.ignore = ':not(select:hidden, input:visible, textarea:visible)';
        }
```

There still could be potential issues, but for my needs this solution works good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the display:none property given from bootstrap select skin to the original select (jQuery validate ignores hidden fields).
It could be avoided working only with CSS keeping back visible the original select but giving it some properties to avoid visibility

```
select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker 
{
    display:block !important; opacity:0; height:1px; width:1px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess, editing of bootstrap-select.js may solve this issue permanently.
I have tried something like this:

```
$(document)
        .data('keycount', 0)
        .on('keydown.bs.select', '.bootstrap-select [data-toggle=dropdown], .bootstrap-select [role="listbox"], .bs-searchbox input', Selectpicker.prototype.keydown)
        .on('focusin.modal', '.bootstrap-select [data-toggle=dropdown], .bootstrap-select [role="listbox"], .bs-searchbox input', function (e) {
            //Validation handler: Kartik
            var $thisParent = $(this).parent(".bootstrap-select");
            if ($thisParent.find("ul").find("li:first").hasClass("selected")) {
                if ($thisParent.next("span").length > 0)
                    $thisParent.next("span").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                if ($thisParent.next("span").length > 0)
                    $thisParent.next("span").css("display", "none");
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Its working fine to me.