# How to make bootstrap selectpicker border red when validation fail

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using [jquery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) library. i want to make border of select-picker red when validation fail.
jquery validation have class `error`. i apply on input text field work fine.but not on select-picker .here is my input error class css

```
input[class="form-control error"], input[class="error"] {
border: 1px solid #D72839 !important;
                                                        }
```

but when i apply on select its not red border

```
select[class="form-control error"], select[class="error"] {
border: 1px solid #D72839 !important;
                                                        }
```

After inspect element when validation fail code look like

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker error" name="scity" id="scity"
data-live-search="true" title="Select city" tabindex="-98">
<option value="2">New York</option>
</select>
<label for="scity" generated="true" class="error"><p>Select City</p></label>
```

here you can see error class , but how can i apply red border on select picker when validation fail.
thanks

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315242/validation-of-bootstrap-select-using-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: Just `add` `error` class on validation fail as you're doing and use `css` `.error {border:1px solid red}`

Comment: not working....

Comment: You're applying your error class to `<select>` but the Bootstrap Select plugin replaces the entire `<select>` element for its functionality.  Are you applying your CSS to the new elements it creates?